# Why does my Three.JS Environment Map Move?

Tags: three.js

I have an a cubecamera at (0,0,0) as well as a giant sphere around it (textured on the inside).

The cubecamera creates a cubemap which is applied as the environment map for a second, smaller sphere.

When the second sphere moves on the screen its environment map reflection also moves.

**My question is why does it move?**

1. I am using an orthographic camera so I am always looking at the
   smaller sphere flat on, even if it moves left/right.
2. The cubecamera is the source of the environment map and **the
   cubecamera does not move.**
3. The giant sphere which the cubecamera builds its map from also does
   not move.

Answer (score 0):

Environment mapping is a projection from the environment to your object, here the small sphere. So if the object changes position the mapping changes also. It does not matter it you are projecting using an orthographic camera or a perspective camera. It is still a positional based mapping.

Comment: Are you saying it is because the distance between part of the environment map and the sphere is changing? I thought that the cubemap was considered infinite in size. I just did a quick test and changing the size/resolution of the cubecamera does not make any difference.

Comment: The cubecamera provides the environment i.e. cubemap. But you say you move the small sphere. So then the projection changes.

Comment: I would like to modify the variable that effects how much it changes. I am only moving the sphere relative to the screen. Left/right relative to the orthographic camera. So I dont understand why it changes.

Comment: I think you would need to implement the environment mapping part yourself.

Comment: I have had a look at the shader implementation in three.js but this is what I do not understand. If I move the sphere by x amount to the left the reflection rotates around the sphere. But what is it that determines how much I have to move it to the left to get Y amount of rotation in the reflection? It is not the cameras fov because there is none, it is orthographic.

Comment: that is not even done in the three.js stage but at the webgl stage. so you would have to find the opengl es spec at https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.1/es_spec_3.1.pdf under cube maps.

Comment: So what is it moving relative to if the cubemap is considered infinitely far away?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?